# pass jvm flags to the gradle application

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I want to add some flags to the JVM machine of my gradle application. My gradle version is 4.0.2.

i know the basic solution where you can create the jar and pass it to the jar but i would like the things to be passed through gradle.properties.

I have tried this ->

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Ddd.service.name=stestmeee -Ddatadog.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug -javaagent:/home/tilak/IdeaProjects/datadog-springboot/dd-java-agent.jar
org.gradle.daemon=false
```

Running jps -lvm command returns me this ->

```
5585 org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer -Djava.awt.headless=true -Didea.version==2019.1.3 -Xmx768m -Didea.maven.embedder.version=3.3.9 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
20086 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 4.10.3 --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant
4378 com.intellij.idea.Main -Xms128m -Xmx1150m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine -Dsun.tools.attach.tmp.only=true -Dide.no.platform.update=true -XX:ErrorFile=/home/tilak/java_error_in_IDEA_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/tilak/java_error_in_IDEA.hprof -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2019.1 -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/home/tilak/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/191.7479.19.vmoptions -Didea.platform.prefix=Idea -Didea.jre.check=true
25868 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 4.10.3 -javaagent:/home/tilak/IdeaProjects/datadog-springboot/dd-java-agent.jar --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant
28557 com.SpringBootApplication -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant
28350 org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain bootRun -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradle
28382 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 4.4.1 -javaagent:/home/tilak/IdeaProjects/datadog-springboot/dd-java-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant
29359 jdk.jcmd/sun.tools.jps.Jps -lvm -Dapplication.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 -Xms8m -Djdk.module.main=jdk.jcmd
```

seems like my flags are not getting set?

Am i doing something wrong?

I am just stuck on this for the past two days.

Comment: If you are using IntelliJIdea as IDE, you can configure it from the menu. Here is more: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Comment: this passes to the intellij jvm not the application jvm.

Comment: My bad! I misunderstood your question.

Comment: From the docs, `org.gradle.jvmargs` specifies the JVM arguments used for the Gradle Daemon. The Gradle daemon can then spawn your application; but these parameters are not propagated. See refs at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Comment: Can you provide more info- how exactly are you running your application from Gradle? If using Exec task or running tests; there are other ways to pass JVM parameters